# Android CardView cardCornerRadius gap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-support-library

I am trying to use new CardView UI Widget in my project but on some devices running android 2.3 there is a gap between CardView corners (see below).

This is in my xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:contentPadding="50dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/Theme.Apptheme.Color" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And this is the way I see it in the 3.2 QVGA screen AVD

[image: CardView Corner Gap]

In other device like LG Optimus Sol, there is even a veritcal gap.

Is there anyway to prevent this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it seems to be solved with the last support library update.

Comment: You are right. It seems that the new update had the solution for this, thank you.